# Rebuilding web index does not bring the published items

Tags: indexing, lucene

I took a backup from the server and setup the site on my local development environment. (by backup, I mean I took backup of all databases)

I set up staging(CM) and Production(CD) on my local development environment. When I rebuild master index, I got all content on the staging website, but on production website I do not have all contents even after rebuilding the web index. I can see those items under sitecore/content/home in the web database, and when I publish those all items are displaying.

My web index is configured to `onPublishEndAsync` strategy.

I read this very useful [page](https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/index_update_strategies) and I believe that it's because of our strategy we configured for web.  It sound to me like RemoteRebuildStrategy would work but I'm not sure how to configure it, or that's not the solution?

Please help how can I get those items indexed on web index so that I do not need to republish them. I'm working on Sitecore 7.5

Thanks.

Comment: The web Index should ideally update only on publish event and when you rebuild the web Index.

For example, if you have configured Solr as search provider then you just need to open "Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.Index.Web.config" and add the "onPublishEndAsync" and "remoteRebuild" strategies to index configurations.

Answer (score 3):

To trigger a rebuild on a "remote" server that has it's own indexes you need the RemoteRebuild strategy indeed. You can add it to the strategies of your index:

```
<strategies hint="list:AddStrategy">
  <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/onPublishEndAsync" />
  <strategy ref="contentSearch/indexConfigurations/indexUpdateStrategies/remoteRebuild"/>
</strategies>
```

As you might have read on the page you mentioned, this event is triggered when the index is rebuilt (only activated when a full index rebuild takes place). Make sure the EventQueue is enabled, your core database is shared and your indexes have the same name on the cm and cd - but I guess that won't be an issue.